# Flutter gives error when trying to call reload method

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm building a flutter Android application and I'm using Firebase Authentication for managing the user.

[Email Verify view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGc6H.jpg)

See the above email verify view.

I'm trying to refresh the details of my user. Whether the user is verified or not on pressing the continue button. But I'm getting the following errors:

I'm getting the below message for await user.reload();

> The method 'reload' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

I'm  getting the below message for user = await AuthService.firebase().currentUser();

> The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'.

My code for OnPressed :

```
onPressed: () async {
  var user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
  await user.reload();
  user = await AuthService.firebase().currentUser();
  if (user?.isEmailVerified ?? false) {
    // user's email is verified
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      passwordsRoute,
      (route) => false,
    );
  } else {
    // user's email is NOT verified
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      verifyEmailRoute,
      (route) => false,
    );
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the user can be null so you can use

```
await user?.reload();
```

Comment: Now, I'm getting the 1st error as : 'The method 'reload' isn't defined for the type 'AuthUser'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'reload'.'

and the second error remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Because Your user is get null when you reload your user.
just remove this line

```
await user.reload();
```

because without this your code can work also.
your error is resolved.

Comment: But I want to reload to check whether the user's email is verified or not.

Comment: so you have  to write this line into condition `if (user?.isEmailVerified ?? false) {.            await user.reload();
                // user's email is verified
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  passwordsRoute,
                  (route) => false,
                );
              } `  like this

Comment: but you dont need write it because you can access it when you write like this `AuthService.firebase().currentUser`

Comment: Now, I'm getting the error : 'The method 'reload' isn't defined for the type 'AuthUser'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'reload'

Comment: write this `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.reload()` like this

Comment: So, after entering your code. I imported the FirebaseAuth file and now I'm getting the error : `The method 'getInstance' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getInstance'.`

Comment: `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`. write this